# Why the given code(Program to remove duplicates from a linked list using hashing) is not displaying any output?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I want to write a program that will remove duplicates from a linked list and print the linked list.

I have used a hashing method to achieve this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

unordered_map<int,int> hashmap;
Node* head = NULL;

void deldups()
{
    Node* h = head;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    Node* curr;
    curr = h;
    
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        int val = curr->data;
        if (hashmap.find(val) != hashmap.end())
        {
            if (hashmap[val] > 1)
            {
                prev->next = curr->next->next;
                delete(curr);
            }
        }
        else{
            ++hashmap[val];
            prev = curr;
        }
        curr = prev->next;
    }
}

void print()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    Node* firstnode = new Node();
    head = firstnode;
    firstnode->data = 5;

    Node* secondnode = new Node();
    firstnode->next = secondnode;
    secondnode->data = 6;

    Node* thirdnode = new Node();
    secondnode->next = thirdnode;
    thirdnode->data = 7;

    Node* forthnode = new Node();
    thirdnode->next = forthnode;
    forthnode->data = 5;

    Node* fifthnode = new Node();
    forthnode->next = fifthnode;
    fifthnode->data = 9;
    fifthnode->next = NULL;
    
    deldups();
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

Code Explanation:

1. Traverse the linked list while `ptr` is not NULL, check if the given element (`h->data`) is present in the map (`unordered<int,int>`).

   **NOTE** I am using the element as a key in the map and not its value, the value will be used to count its duplicates.
2. if the key is present then we will check its value, and if the value is greater than '1' i.e the element is present more than one time, then remove the node from the linked list.
3. else, add the element key into the hashmap and increment its value by 1.

After running the code, there is no output. Why?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code does not output anything is because `deldups()` is getting stuck in an infinite loop (which you would see if you run your code in a debugger, or at least have `deldups()` output what it is doing).

When `hashmap.find()` finds a duplicate, `curr` is not being advanced to the next node following the duplicate, so subsequent iterations are finding the same duplicate again and again.  The reason `curr` is not being advanced is because the expression `hashmap[val] > 1` is **never** true, as `hashmap[val]` is not being incremented above 1, so you are not removing the duplicate and advancing `curr` to the next node.

To fix that, you would need to check for `> 0` instead of `> 1`. In which case, you don't actually need to *count* the duplicates anymore, you just need to know whether they *exist*, so using `std::unordered_map` becomes overkill.  Using `std::set` instead would suffice.

After fixing that, this statement is also wrong:

```cpp
prev->next = curr->next->next;
```

You are trashing your list by skipping nodes that don't need to be skipped.  Also, if `curr` is the last node in the list, `next` will be NULL, so accessing `next->next` will be *undefined behavior*.

That statement needs to be this instead:

```cpp
prev->next = curr->next;
```

With that said, try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

set<int> hashmap;
Node* head = NULL;

void deldups()
{
    Node* prev = NULL;
    Node* curr = head;
    
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        int val = curr->data;
        if (!hashmap.insert(val).second)
        {
            prev->next = curr->next;
            delete curr;
        }
        else
        {
            prev = curr;
        }
        curr = prev->next;
    }
}

void print()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    Node* firstnode = new Node();
    head = firstnode;
    firstnode->data = 5;

    Node* secondnode = new Node();
    firstnode->next = secondnode;
    secondnode->data = 6;

    Node* thirdnode = new Node();
    secondnode->next = thirdnode;
    thirdnode->data = 7;

    Node* forthnode = new Node();
    thirdnode->next = forthnode;
    forthnode->data = 5;

    Node* fifthnode = new Node();
    forthnode->next = fifthnode;
    fifthnode->data = 9;
    fifthnode->next = NULL;
    
    deldups();
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/CcVIrW)

That being said, you might consider using the standard `std::list` or `std::forward_list` container instead of a manual linked-list implemented.  Then, you would be able to use the standard `std::unique()` or `std::remove_if()` algorithm to remove duplicates.